# Php order based on switch statement

Tags: php, sorting

For an assignment, (that will never reach the live web so I'm not concerned about using mysql_ statements) I have to make a store. I'v got all the music to display from the database, and got the cart working from a tutorial, but I'm now stuck on how to change the sort order of the output table. I've tried using this code

```
 function products() {

    $order='music_id';
    if (isset($_GET['album'])){
        $order='music_album' ;
        header('Location: '. $page);
    }
    switch($order){
        case 'music_album':
        $get = mysql_query('SELECT music_id, music_artist, music_album, music_genre, music_price FROM music WHERE music_stock > 0 ORDER BY music_album');

    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
        echo "There are no products avaliable, sorry.";
    }

    else {

       echo '<table width="100%" border="0px" class="msc"><tr><td><b>Album</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?album">[Sort]</a></td><td><b>Artist</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?artist">[Sort]</a></td><td><b>Genre</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?genre">[Sort]</a></td><td><b>Price</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?price">[Sort]</a></td></tr>';




while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($get)) {
        echo '<tr> <td> <i>'. $get_row['music_album'] . '</i></td><td>' .$get_row['music_artist'] . '</td><td>' . $get_row['music_genre']. '</td><td>$' . $get_row['music_price'] .'</td><td> <a class="btn" href="cart.php?add='. $get_row['music_id'] . ' ">Add<a></td></tr>';

    }}
    break;
```

using a case for each sort, and a default using music_id, but when the`<a href="cart.php?album">[Sort]</a>` is clicked it neither redirects back to music.php, or changes the sort. Is there a. a better way to perform this task or b. a way I can get this to work?

EDIT
New code, heres the whole function. This gets called on the actual music page, could that be why the sort isn't working?

```
function products() {
     $possible_orders= ['music_album', 'music_artist', 'music_genre', 'music_price'];
   if (isset ($_GET['order'])){
    if (! in_array($order, $possible_orders)){
        $order=$_GET['order'];
    }
    header('Location: '. $page);
   }
   else{
       $order='music_id'; 
   }


$get = mysql_query('SELECT music_id, music_artist, music_album, music_genre, music_price FROM music WHERE music_stock > 0 ORDER BY '.$order);

if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
    echo "There are no products avaliable, sorry.";
}

else {


echo '<table width="100%" border="0px" class="msc"><tr><td><b>Album</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?order=music_album">[Sort]</a></td><td><b>Artist</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?order=music_artist">[Sort]</a></td><td><b>Genre</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?order=music_genre">[Sort]</a></td><td><b>Price</b>&nbsp;<a href="cart.php?order=music_price">[Sort]</a></td></tr>';



    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($get)) {
        echo '<tr> <td> <i>'. $get_row['music_album'] . '</i></td><td>' .$get_row['music_artist'] . '</td><td>' . $get_row['music_genre']. '</td><td>$' . $get_row['music_price'] .'</td><td><hr> <a class="btn" href="cart.php?add='. $get_row['music_id'] . ' ">Add<a><hr></td></tr>';
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: Your link look wrong. Try with `cart.php?album=`

Comment: `header('Location: '. $page);` ... what's `$page`?

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you provided, it could be the function products() is not called on page reload for some reason.

Additionally, you don't really need a switch() statement there. What would be ways better is to provide the value of order in order variable directly at page.

1) fix the links from 'cart.php?album' to 'cart.php?order=album' (and of course the rest of the orderings)

then do sonething like this instead of switch():

```
function products() 
{
    $possible_orders=['music_album', 'music_artist', ... ];
    $order=$_GET['order'];
    if (! in_array($order, $possible_orders))
       $order='music_id'; // rudimentary safety check

    $get=mysql_query(.... ' ORDER BY '.$order);
...
```

Comment: This seems like a much better way of doing things! It works in the sense that the other one did, that I'm not getting errors, but it's still not redirecting or actually sorting.

Comment: (1) Can you quote the html source of the actual webpage for the part where you have PHP code: "echo '<table width="100%" border="0px" class="msc"><tr><td><b>Album"... and (2) did you change that code to what I said in "fix the links... " part of the answer?

Comment: I think that Location header messes everything up. It is used for redirection and I don't see why you should have it there. It probably automatically redirects you to the page with default order as soon as it runs.

Also, you changed the idea of getting the requested order.

Comment: What my code did was:
- set the ordering from requested page query part [the "?order=music_album" part]
- if requested ordering is NOT in valid ordering list then assign default ordering (by music_id)

What your updated code does:
- if ordering is set in page query, then use it, if it is not a valid ordering. 
- then immediately move from current page to $page (by adding Location header). This can't possibly work.